# Can Horovod with TensorFlow work on non-GPU instances in Amazon SageMaker?

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker, distributed-training, horovod

I want to perform **distributed training** on **Amazon SageMaker**. The code is written with **TensorFlow** and similar to the following code where I think CPU instance should be enough: 
https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/master/examples/tensorflow_word2vec.py

Can **Horovod with TensorFlow** work on **non-GPU** instances in Amazon SageMaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you should be able to use both CPU's and GPU's with Horovod on Amazon SageMaker. Please follow the below example for the same

https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_script_mode_horovod/tensorflow_script_mode_horovod.ipynb